How to shrink log file for Azure SQL Database?
My Azure Sql Database transaction log file is about 1 TB in size, but only 1 GB is in use:
SELECT file_id, name, type_desc,
CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS decimal(19,4)) * 8 / 1024. AS space_used_mb,
CAST(size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS int)/128.0 AS decimal(19,4)) AS space_unused_mb,
CAST(size AS decimal(19,4)) * 8 / 1024. AS space_allocated_mb,
CAST(max_size AS decimal(19,4)) * 8 / 1024. AS max_size_mb
FROM sys.database_files;

Results:

I'm trying to cut it down to 50 GB in size, but neither of these seem to have any effect, the space_unused_mb and space_allocated_mb values remain the same:
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, truncateonly);
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 50000);

Or am I barking up the wrong tree here? Does log file size count against storage cost?

From how the pricing calculator works looks like it is chargeable but just sized automatically based on the data size selected (a ~30% overhead on top of that). I doubt that the size is changeable by us

Azure SQL Database automatically shrinks transaction log file to avoid excessive space usage that can lead to out-of-space errors. It is usually not necessary to shrink the transaction log file.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, TRUNCATEONLY);

But the transaction log size may not be reducible until the next transaction log backup is completed.
It appears that the definitive solution is:
ALTER DATABASE <db> SET AUTO_SHRINK ON;

Usually, it is not a good option on prem but on Azure it is acceptable.
However, if you're utilizing Azure SQL Database in Hyperscale, the scenario differs as shrinking the database was not possible. Recently, Microsoft has introduced the capability to shrink databases in public preview.
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/public-preview-shrink-for-azure-sql-database-hyperscale/ba-p/4181976

"Usually, it is not a good option on prem but on Azure it is acceptable." - Why?

From my experience, manually managing the database size on-premises is a good practice. However, with an Azure SQL database, it can sometimes feel tedious, like trying to clear water from a beach. Having auto-shrink enabled is convenient for resolving issues and minimizing effort.
You can at least try it, and if necessary, you can always revert back after some time.

I agree with MBuschi. This is the reason why @J.D. : https://www.jeeja.biz/2024/05/12/myth-busters-who-is-scared-of-auto_shrink/

@FrancescoMantovani Sure, but that article is based on the premise "The cost of the SQL Elastic Pool doesn’t justify moving to it", when the cost of being in the cloud in general isn't justified itself. So it's not surprising using something previously known as bad practice to make something else like the cloud suck less. It's still all not great. And basic guidelines still apply such as when you've grown from 100 GB to 1 TB from a specific event, you can manually shrink for those one-off cases.

@J.D. Both DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0) and DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (N'db1') are simply not working in an Azure SQL Database scenario. Have you tried them?

@FrancescoMantovani Despite that being a copy/pasta from the article, it doesn't change what I said.

What do you mean @J.D. ? That is a copy/paste from my article. That is my blog. I tested Both DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0) and DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (N'db1') on dozens of Azure SQL Databases and after month of trying to use alternative I had to use AUTO_SHRINK because there was no alternative. And it turned out that there were no drawbacks as AUTO_SHRINK on Azure uses zero CPU, Memory and I/O Log and is able to remove hundreds of Gigabites in less than a minute with flat CPU. I don't know how to explain that but you have the screenshot in the article. Try yourself.

@FrancescoMantovani I did wonder if that was your blog. What I meant is I already read what you copy/pasted from it. I read the whole article actually. And it's a decent article indeed. But I don't think it conclusively tests AUTO_SHRINK, and you even said in the article in an update that you did find some CPU usage (there's no such thing as a free lunch). What I mean by what I said before doesn't change is that there are multiple ways to manually shrink a database back down besides the commands. I can't tell you why the commands themselves don't work in Azure though as I don't use it.

All good @J.D. and sorry if it sounds like I raised my voice. We are all here to learn. I probably haven't emphasized enough that I have tested AUTO_SHRING in a database park of >200 Dbs. And for nearly 1 year now. I just discussed today how we should enable it on 3 more databases to make them fit into an Elastic Pool. For now I haven't see any drawbacks. Am I the only fish in the pond seeing this? Not sure. If I write another article what would you like me to write about this topic? What am I missing?

@FrancescoMantovani "sorry if it sounds like I raised my voice" - No worries, you're good. I didn't take it that way. "If I write another article what would you like me to write about this topic?" - Why the typical shrink commands don't work in Azure, haha. I'd be more curious to why that's so, personally. Assuming that Microsoft hasn't outright said they're not supported yet. But yea I'm just not a fan of Cloud overall so far. Maybe one day it'll be better.

To recover log space you can run the following statement.
DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0)

Setting the target size to 0 will shrink the log file as much as possible, but it won't shrink it below the size needed to store the active portion of the log. If you are using Azure SQL Hyperscale then shrinking is not a supported operation.

if DBCC SHRINKFILE (2, 50000); doesn't work, why would DBCC SHRINKFILE (log, 0); work?

It has worked for me on some scenarios. Setting the target size to 0 will shrink the log file as much as possible, but it won't shrink it below the size needed to store the active portion of the log. If you are using Azure SQL Hyperscale then it won't work because shrink is not supported. As you can read here  my suggestions do usually work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45829322/reduce-azure-sql-database-size/45830080#45830080

ok, I'm sing hyperscale, that's why it won't work.
